# javascript if statement multiple operators failing

Tags: javascript, if-statement, operators

I have an if statement which evaluates

```
if(expression || expression &&
   expression || expression){

   //logic
}
```

for a reason I cannot understand, the else statement after the and operator does not get evaluated. Is there some rules to the if statement that I do not know of?

Here is my code:

```
const fillTable = function (array) {
    let tbody = document.querySelector("#tblbody");
    while (tbody.firstChild) {
        tbody.removeChild(tbody.firstChild);
    }
    array.forEach(element => {
        let region = regionOption.options[regionOption.selectedIndex].value;
        let gender = genderOption.options[regionOption.selectedIndex].value;
        elementGender = Object.values(element)[2];
        elementRegion = Object.values(element)[3];
        console.log(elementRegion + "+" + region);
        console.log(elementGender + "+" + gender);

        if (elementRegion === region || region === "All" &&
            elementGender === gender || gender === "bot") {
            let tr = document.createElement("tr");
            tbody.appendChild(tr);
            const values = Object.values(element);
            values.forEach(element => {
                let td = document.createElement("td");
                td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(element));
                tr.appendChild(td);
            })
        }
    })
};
```

the loop continues even though the genders does not match in the if statement.

Comment: Order of operations... A good linter built into your IDE would be yelling at you for this. :)

Comment: @epascarello I am using Visual Studio Code for this. No warnings :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably getting tripped up on operator precedence.  If the boolean expressions before and after the `&&` are supposed to be grouped, explicitly group them:

```
if((expression || expression) &&
   (expression || expression))
```

Even in the absence of operator precedence rules, it's always best to be clear and explicit about the logic you're expressing.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, I will mark you as soon as I am able to

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the 2 lines from the `if` condition should each be within their own [grouping operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping):

```
if (
       (expression1 || expression2)
    && (expression3 || expression4)
) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you intended this

```
if ((elementRegion === region || region === "All") && 
     (elementGender === gender || gender === "bot"))
```

All the logical operators are chaining without parenthesis.